# Struggling with input

Tags: python, input

Rather new to programming, wanted to play around with input and I hit a stump

```
print("Alrighty. Are you male or female?")
gender_choice1 = print("A) Other")
gender_choice2 = print("B) Male")
gender_choice3 = print("C) Female")

gender_answer1 = "of course"

gender_answer2 = "Of course sir"

gender_answer3 = "Of course madame"

if input() == "a":
    print(gender_answer1)
    
if input() == "b":
    print(gender_answer2)
    
if input() == "c":
    print(gender_answer3)
```

every time I try to answer anything other than "a" it refuses to print anything and just puts out a blank space.

Comment: You ask the same question three times. Instead of doing that, store return value and compare that: `ans = input('Alrighty, are you male or female') # check the ans`

Comment: Tangentially, this looks like you want to use a dictiorary or tuple to map inputs to outputs. `answer = {'a': ''; 'b': 'sir', 'c': 'madam'}; print('Very good', answer[ans])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call `input()`, Python will try to read new input. So each of your `input()` calls in your `if`-conditions will have different inputs. If you want each of them to compare the same input, assign `input()` to a variable first.

```
i = input()

if i == "a":
    print(gender_answer1)
    
if i == "b":
    print(gender_answer2)
   
if i == "c":
    print(gender_answer3)
```